# Hash algorithm in C to map 16 byte-values to 2 byte-values

Tags: c, algorithm, hashmap

I'm working on an electronic project with a microcontroller which is programmed in C.

I need to store some IDs and its associated information in a flash memory (SD). These IDs are 16 bytes long so there are 2^128 possible values. Although they are 16 bytes, only 50000 (unique) values will be used. It's physically impossible to store all the possible (2^128) IDs in a SD.

I could store only the 50000 used values but then I would have to traverse all (at worst) of them to find the one I need. Besides, it would have to be computed a 16-byte values comparison for each of them which makes it to be quite slow.

So I think I would need some kind of (hash?) function that maps the 2^128 values to 50000 (map 16 bytes to 2 bytes). It's obvious that some of the original values will map to the same value/index. The idea is that when I get an ID, I apply a hash function which gives me an index between 0 and ~50000 (0-65535). With that index I can directly access the SD sector(s) in which the ID and its associated info is stored. As I have pointed out, that index will refer to a position of memory where various IDs will coexist due to some different IDs getting mapped to the same index value. I would have to find the correct ID but it would cost only a few comparison instead of the 50000 original ones.

Any idea/opinion would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are reinventing the concept of "hash table" - google it.

Comment: Simply add all the bytes?

Comment: Hash the keys with a 16bit checksum or hash. My first shot would be CRC16.

Comment: You are on the right track, you probably need hashing with [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing)

Comment: use *any* sane hash function, and use its value modulo 50000 as a table index. To avoid calls to the hashfunction, you *could* choose to  store the hashvalues in the table, too.

Comment: "I would have to traverse all (at worst) of them to find the one I need" - not necessarily. Consider for example a binary search, which would require up to 16 comparisons. More than the expected number of comparisons for a hashtable lookup, but still quite low. If you know all the IDs when you populate your SD storage then all you need is to sort them before writing them.

Comment: Follow Steve's advice. And take a course or two in algorithms.

Comment: There are perfect hash implementations out there? Google for "perfect hash"

Comment: reading from SD card may be slow for binary search, but if your data is constant, you can sort it before storing it into the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use 16 MSB of actual id. It's dumb but with your details it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Sure Mat's is fine, this however, by use of a prime should result in less collisions where `uuid[x] == uuid[y]` (and `x!=y`)

```
uint32_t uuid[4];

uint16_t hash = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   // hash *= 31; //next line does this, note 31 is a prime
   hash = (hash << 5) - hash;
   hash += (uuid[i] & 0xffff) ^ (uuid[i] >> 16);
}
```

Or this version is even better, because it reduces clashes where the xor of the first 16 bits and second 16 bits match.

```
uint16_t hash = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   hash = (hash << 5) - hash; //(*=31)
   hash += uuid[i] & 0xffff;
   hash = (hash << 5) - hash; //(*=31)
   hash += uuid[i] >> 16;
}
```

Comment: Note that due to operator precedence, depending on your programming language you may want to put parenthses on your left-shift: `hash = (hash << 5) - hash;` For reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_precedence#Programming_languages

Comment: @K.Brafford Indeed in `c` `-` is higher precedence that `<<`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the ID is 16 bytes long, I guees that it's stored in a ASCII string, so ELFhash perhaps works.

```
int ELFhash(char *key) {
    unsigned long h = 0;
    while(*key) {
        h = (h << 4) + *key++;
        unsigned long g = h & 0xf0000000L;
        if (g) h ^= g >> 24;
        h &= -g;
    }
    return h & M;
}
```

where M is a prime number smaller than 65536, or 50000.

It's more likely that the prefix of many ID strings are of the same because they represent for a specific meaaing, so you should be more careful to prevent collisions, or the linked list will be very long.

Comment: Is it known the probability of collision?

Answer (score 0):

Assumign the bits in your 128-bit value are "uniformly distributed", you could simply do something like this:

```
 uint32_t uuid[4];

 uint16_t hash = 0;
 for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
     hash ^= (uuid[i] & 0xffff) ^ (uuid[i] >> 16);
 }
```

There are probably other more clever ways, but this one is very simple, and may work well enough.

Comment: If they're uniformly distributed, you could just return `uuid[i] & 0xffff` and be done with it.

Comment: That would possibly work too, yes [as SAM suggests in another answer].